# Queue family ownership transfer granularity for VkBuffer

Tags: vulkan

Question: Are there any granularity/alignment requirements for transfering sub-regions of a VkBuffer from one queue family to another?

I would like to:

1. use a single graphics/present queue for sourcing draw calls from a single VkBuffer;
2. and another separate compute queue to fill sub-allocated regions/sections within said VkBuffer

So, commands submitted to the graphics/present queue (1.) will read/source data written to the VkBuffer by commands submitted to the compute queue (2.). And I do not want to transfer *the whole* VkBuffer from one queue to the other, but only certain sub-regions (once their computation is finished and the results can be consumed/sourced by the graphics commands).

I've read that whenever you use `VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE` VkSharingMode you must explicitly transfer ownership from one queue (in my case the compute queue) to the other queue (in my case the graphics/present queue) such that commands submitted to the latter queue sees the changes made by submitted commands in the former queue.
I know how to do this and how to correctly synchronize both release and acquire actions with semaphores.

However, since I wanted to use a singe VkBuffer with manual sub-allocations (actually with VMA virtual allocations) and saw that [VkBufferMemoryBarrier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkBufferMemoryBarrier.html) provides an `offset` and `size` properties, I was wondering whether there are any granularity requirements as for which sections/pages of a VkBuffer can be transferred.

Can I actually transfer *single bytes* of a VkBuffer from one queue family to another or do I have to obey certain granularity/alignment requirements (other than the alignment requirements for my own data structures within that VkBuffer and the usage of that buffer of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no granularity requirements on queue family transfer byte ranges. Indeed, there do not appear to be granularity requirements on memory barrier byte ranges either.

Comment: @KaiBurjack: Well that's all I looked for. Granularity requirements are spelled out in VUs.